# How to remove blank page, header and page number (memoir, gantt)

Tags: memoir, pgfgantt

I'm using `pgfgantt` package with memoir, and what I'm getting is a blank page, and I couldn't find a command to help remove the header and[image] the page number.

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir} % Change font size here (allowable values are 9pt-12pt), change the paper size, specify one or two sided printing and specify whether to show trimming lines
%
\usepackage{color} % Required for custom colors
 \definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
%Used to draw gantt charts, which I will use for the calendar.
%Let's define some awesome new ganttchart elements:
\definecolor{foobaryellow}{RGB}{234,187,0}

\newganttchartelement{blackmain}{
    blackmain/.style={
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw=red!66!black,
        thick,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=black
    },
    blackmain label font=\bfseries \footnotesize,
 blackmain left shift=0,
 blackmain right shift=0,
}

\newganttchartelement{blackbar}{
    blackbar/.style={
draw=black,
  bottom color=red,
       rounded corners=3pt
    },
   blackbar label font=\slshape \footnotesize,
    blackbar left shift=.1,
   blackbar right shift=-.1
}

\begin{document}


\afterpage{\begin{landscape}


\small

\begin{ganttchart}[expand chart=0.95\paperwidth,
    hgrid style/.style={black, dotted},
    vgrid={*5{black,dotted}, *1{white, dotted}},
    x unit=0.2mm,
    y unit chart=8mm,
    y unit title=9mm,
    time slot format=isodate,
    title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
    title height=0.7,
    group label font=\bfseries \footnotesize,
    milestone label font=\bfseries \footnotesize\color{lava},
    milestone inline label node/.append style={left=5mm},
    link/.style={->, thick},
    group left shift=0,
group right shift=0,
  group peaks tip position=0.2,
  group peaks width=1mm,
  group peaks height=.4,
  milestone left shift=-2mm,
  milestone right shift=2mm,
  milestone height=0.2mm,
    ]{2022-01-01}{2022-12-31}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month}\\

    \ganttgroup[]{Proof of Concept}{2022-01-01}{2022-04-29}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar[name=Circuit design 
    ]{Circuit design}{2022-01-01}{2022-01-23}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar[
    ]{Procure equipment}{2022-01-24}{2022-01-31}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar[
    ]{Provision Circuits}{2022-02-01}{2022-04-07}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar[]{Paper Drafting}{2022-04-08}{2022-04-29}\\ [grid]
        \ganttmilestone{Submission}{2022-04-29}\\ [grid]
        
      \ganttgroup[]{Performance Evaluation}{2022-04-29}{2022-07-29}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Develop Models}{2022-04-29}{2022-05-29}\\ [grid]
        \ganttblackbar{Obtain Results}{2022-05-29}{2022-07-7}\\ [grid]
        \ganttblackbar[name=Paper Drafting]{Paper Drafting}{2022-07-7}{2022-07-29}\\ [grid]

    \ganttmilestone{Submission}{2022-07-29}\\ [grid]



      \ganttgroup[]{Practical Outdoor Evaluation}{2022-07-29}{2022-12-31}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Circuit design}{2022-07-29}{2022-08-29}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Provision Circuits}{2022-08-29}{2022-09-29}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Results Evaluation}{2022-09-29}{2022-10-15}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Results Fine Tuning}{2022-10-15}{2022-10-30}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Paper Drafting}{2022-10-30}{2022-11-30}\\ [grid]
     \ganttmilestone{Submission}{2022-11-30}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Submitting for Funding}{2022-11-15}{2022-12-31}


\end{ganttchart}
\end{landscape}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\afterpage{\begin{landscape}` is forcing a page break after the current page. Why have you got that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gantt` chart is too wide and long to fit on a single page. Consider splitting it in two.

[image: a]

Use `\pagestyle{empty}` to suppress headers and page numbers,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir} % Change font size here (allowable values are 9pt-12pt), change the paper size, specify one or two sided printing and specify whether to show trimming lines
%
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for custom colors
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}


%Used to draw gantt charts, which I will use for the calendar.
%Let's define some awesome new ganttchart elements:
\definecolor{foobaryellow}{RGB}{234,187,0}

\newganttchartelement{blackmain}{
    blackmain/.style={
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw=red!66!black,
        thick,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=black
    },
    blackmain label font=\bfseries \footnotesize,
    blackmain left shift=0,
    blackmain right shift=0,
}

\newganttchartelement{blackbar}{
    blackbar/.style={
        draw=black,
        bottom color=red,
        rounded corners=3pt
    },
    blackbar label font=\slshape \footnotesize,
    blackbar left shift=.1,
    blackbar right shift=-.1
}

\begin{document}
    

\begin{landscape}   

\pagestyle{empty}% suppress headers and page numbers <<<<<<<<<<

\small  

\noindent\begin{ganttchart}[expand chart=0.95\paperwidth,
    hgrid style/.style={black, dotted},
    vgrid={*5{black,dotted}, *1{white, dotted}},
    x unit=0.2mm,
    y unit chart=8mm,
    y unit title=9mm,
    time slot format=isodate,
    title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
    title height=0.7,
    group label font=\bfseries \footnotesize,
    milestone label font=\bfseries \footnotesize\color{lava},
    milestone inline label node/.append style={left=5mm},
    link/.style={->, thick},
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group peaks tip position=0.2,
    group peaks width=1mm,
    group peaks height=.4,
    milestone left shift=-2mm,
    milestone right shift=2mm,
    milestone height=0.2mm,
    ]{2022-01-01}{2022-08-15}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month}\\
    
    \ganttgroup[]{Proof of Concept}{2022-01-01}{2022-04-29}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar[name=Circuit design 
    ]{Circuit design}{2022-01-01}{2022-01-23}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar[
    ]{Procure equipment}{2022-01-24}{2022-01-31}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar[
    ]{Provision Circuits}{2022-02-01}{2022-04-07}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar[]{Paper Drafting}{2022-04-08}{2022-04-29}\\ [grid]
    \ganttmilestone{Submission}{2022-04-29}\\ [grid]
    
    \ganttgroup[]{Performance Evaluation}{2022-04-29}{2022-07-29}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Develop Models}{2022-04-29}{2022-05-29}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Obtain Results}{2022-05-29}{2022-07-7}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar[name=Paper Drafting]{Paper Drafting}{2022-07-7}{2022-07-29}\\ [grid]
    
    \ganttmilestone{Submission}{2022-07-29}\\ [grid]
\end{ganttchart}                

    
\noindent\begin{ganttchart}[expand chart=0.95\paperwidth,
    hgrid style/.style={black, dotted},
    vgrid={*5{black,dotted}, *1{white, dotted}},
    x unit=0.2mm,
    y unit chart=8mm,
    y unit title=9mm,
    time slot format=isodate,
    title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
    title height=0.7,
    group label font=\bfseries \footnotesize,
    milestone label font=\bfseries \footnotesize\color{lava},
    milestone inline label node/.append style={left=5mm},
    link/.style={->, thick},
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group peaks tip position=0.2,
    group peaks width=1mm,
    group peaks height=.4,
    milestone left shift=-2mm,
    milestone right shift=2mm,
    milestone height=0.2mm,
    ]{2022-07-01}{2022-12-31}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month}\\      
    
    \ganttgroup[]{Practical Outdoor Evaluation}{2022-07-29}{2022-12-31}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Circuit design}{2022-07-29}{2022-08-29}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Provision Circuits}{2022-08-29}{2022-09-29}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Results Evaluation}{2022-09-29}{2022-10-15}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Results Fine Tuning}{2022-10-15}{2022-10-30}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Paper Drafting}{2022-10-30}{2022-11-30}\\ [grid]
    \ganttmilestone{Submission}{2022-11-30}\\ [grid]
    \ganttblackbar{Submitting for Funding}{2022-11-15}{2022-12-31}  
\end{ganttchart}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

The second page can also be drawn with repeating elements to link the chart to the previous timeline.

[image: b]